# Why do 2 Identical codes in C give me different output?

Tags: c, pointers

I am learning about pointers in C, so I wrote this code to do a simple sum calculation from the user's input.

The *test* file:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {

   int i, x[6], sum = 0;

   printf("enter 6 numbers: ");

   for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
      scanf("%d", x+i);
      sum += *(x+1);
   }



   printf("Sum = %d", sum);

   return 0;
}
```

When I run the code, I put `1 2 3 4 5 6` as my user input, which basically does 1+2+3+4+5+6. The output should be 21

```
┌─[✗]─[shogun@parrot]─[~/Documents]
└──╼ $cd "/home/shogun/Documents/" && gcc test.c -o test && "/home/shogun/Documents/"test
enter 6 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6
Sum = 22029
```

**HOWEVER**
I have another code called *test2*
It's identical to the previous one.

```c
#include <stdio.h>
int main() {

  int i, x[6], sum = 0;

  printf("Enter 6 numbers: ");

  for(i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
      scanf("%d", x+i);
      sum += *(x+i);
  }

  printf("Sum = %d\n", sum);

  return 0;
}
```

And yet when I run the code and input the same exact numbers 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, I'll get 21 as result.

```
┌─[✗]─[shogun@parrot]─[~/Documents]
└──╼ $cd "/home/shogun/Documents/" && gcc test2.c -o test2 && "/home/shogun/Documents/"test2
Enter 6 numbers: 1 2 3 4 5 6
Sum = 21
```

Why does this happen?

Shouldn't I get the same output for the same code?

Comment: Do you not find anything different between these two: ```*(x+i)```, ```*(x+1)```?

Comment: Unless this was one of those artificially pedagogical exercises that says you must "use pointers not arrays", *please*, make things easier on yourself and write `x[i]` rather than `*(x+i)`.  You can also write `scanf("%d", &x[i]);` instead of `scanf("%d", x+i);`.

Answer (score 1):

The two code snippets are not the same - one does sum += *(x+i), and the other does sum += *(x+1) (with a 1 instead of i)